# Choosing cards from 2 different suits

Tags: combinatorics

We have 52 cards of 4 suits in total (13 per suit).
We want to choose 5 cards such that all cards are from 2 different suits.

I thought about choosing 2 suits out of 4, then choosing 5 out of 26 and then getting rid of the options in which all cards are of one suit.

$({4 \atop 2})*(({26 \atop 5})-2({13 \atop 5}))$

Am I right?

Comment: At first glance it seems ok.

Comment: Should note:  the problem statement doesn't mention that both suits must actually be present in the hand.  That's certainly a natural requirement, but it should be stated as part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct and a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!